# Loop only certain array key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I loop to display the values of array key `type` without looping other keys because am have more than 500 array lines and reduce time.

```
$details = array(
    array('year' => '1990'),
    array('year' => '1995'),
    array('condition' => 'working'),
    array('type' => 'bus'),
    array('type' => 'car'),
    array('type' => 'bike'),
);
```

Comment: There is no clever way without touching all the records I guess

Comment: If possible consider changing your data structure i.e. `$details['type'] = array('bus','car','bike')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/array_column) introduced in PHP 5.5 (however this still internally loops through the entire array to gather which sub arrays have this key):

```
<?php

$details = array_column($details, 'year');

print_r($details);

/*
    Array
    (
        [0] => 1990
        [1] => 1995
    )
*/
```

[**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/ZKVBD#v550)

[For older versions of PHP the author himself has a polyfill on github](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column).

Comment: What you think about PHP's Prevoius versions ?

Comment: @InventorX Huh? How far back? PHP 5.3+ is usually fine? What do you mean?

Comment: Means PHP 5.3+ and less then PHP 5.5

Comment: array_column I guess is introduced before 5.5

Comment: @RoyalBg Look at the manual: `(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)`. Also look at the demo linking to 3v4l.org.

Comment: It seems I have some crafted PHP 5.3 where it works :) tbh I haven't read its docs before

Comment: @RoyalBg That's odd - are you sure that you don't run the polyfill somewhere in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the solution h2ooooooo. many hosting providers are running php 5.2.x and so I think to use ramsey's alternate solution as you mentioned. Thanks again

Comment: @devdarsh Sure - that's fine. :-) The polyfill essentially just is there so you don't have to recreate the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Array

```
$details = array(
    array('year' => '1990'),
    array('year' => '1995'),
    array('condition' => 'working'),
    array('type' => 'bus'),
    array('type' => 'car'),
    array('type' => 'bike'),
);
```

Create Array that contain only "Type" index

```
$names = array_map(function ($v)
        { 
            return $v['type']; 
        }, 
        $details);

$names = array_filter($names);      

print_r($names);
```

Output

```
Array ( [3] => bus [4] => car [5] => bike )
```

Comment: use array_values() to reset the keys, and pretty nice solution really.